# How to make buttons and links on my page appear on the same height without changing the hover effect?

Tags: html, css

The problem is whenever I change the padding of the buttons to fit the links height, I got a small white space in the hover effect for the links. You can see that in the fiddle below:

```
.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #b58b23;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown .drpbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #b58b23;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m8yb8645/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two `padding`'s don't match, but they should in order to solve your problem:

```
.navbar a {
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

.dropdown .drpbtn {
  padding: 17px 16px; /* needs to match with the above, so 14px 16px */
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8yb8645/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside your link CSS. Actually when you are giving padding your padding equally affect 14px from top and bottom but due to that, only the bottom is not covered so I suggest you to add the following CSS code to your navbar anchor tag.

> padding-bottom: 19px;

into .navbar a {...}

This might solve your problem but it is not a good habit Instead you use the bootstrap that is more helpful.